# Change Magento WSDL element output

Tags: orders, api, soap, wsdl

I need to update some elements/variables of my wsdl output. For example I want to change "shipping_amount" so it gives me the amount incl. tax and not (as it is now) without tax:

```
<complexType name="salesOrderEntity">
   <all>
      ...
      <element name="shipping_amount" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
      ...
   </all>
</complexType>
```

Same goes for the element "price". I want to edit it so it gives me the amount incl. tax.

```
<complexType name="salesOrderItemEntity">
   <all>
      ...
      <element name="price" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
      ...
   </all>
</complexType>
```

In what file is this element "built" or retrieved so i can edit the output of it? The elements I am talking about are found in:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml